# How to select rows from data.frame with 2 conditions

Tags: r

I have an aggregated table:

```
> aggdata[1:4,]
  Group.1 Group.2         x
1       4    0.05 0.9214660
2       6    0.05 0.9315789
3       8    0.05 0.9526316
4      10    0.05 0.9684211
```

How can I select the x value when I have values for Group.1 and Group.2?

I tried:

```
aggdata[aggdata[,"Group.1"]==l && aggdata[,"Group.2"]==lamda,"x"]
```

but that replies all x's.

More info:
I want to use this like this:

```
table = data.frame();
for(l in unique(aggdata[,"Group.1"])) {
    for(lambda in unique(aggdata[,"Group.2"])) {
        table[l,lambda] = aggdata[aggdata[,"Group.1"]==l & aggdata[,"Group.2"]==lambda,"x"]
    }
}
```

Any suggestions that are even easier and giving this result I appreciate!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use & not &&. The latter only evaluates the first element of each vector.

**Update:** to answer the second part, use the reshape package. Something like this will do it:

```
tablex <- recast(aggdata, Group.1 ~ variable * Group.2, id.var=1:2)
# Now add useful column and row names
colnames(tablex) <- gsub("x_","",colnames(tablex))
rownames(tablex) <- tablex[,1]
# Finally remove the redundant first column
tablex <- tablex[,-1]
```

Someone with more experience using reshape may have a simpler solution.

Note: Don't use table as a variable name as it conflicts with the table() function.

Comment: Thanks! It seems indeed to select 1 element. Now however, my loop gives the error: "Error in x[[jj]] <- vjj[FALSE] : attempt to select less than one element" Is it still incorrect?

Comment: That error is generated because you use table[l,lambda] when lambda is less than one.

Comment: I can't figure out what you are trying to do as the group elements are not unique.

Comment: I aggregated a table on L and lambda, taking the mean of some value (aggregate command). So in the table there is a unique value for every combination of Group.1 and Group.2. I would like to construct a table/matrix with two dimensions, Group.1 and Group.2

Answer (score 28):

The easiest solution is to change "&&" to "&" in your code.

```
> aggdata[aggdata[,"Group.1"]==6 & aggdata[,"Group.2"]==0.05,"x"]
[1] 0.9315789
```

My preferred solution would be to use subset():

```
> subset(aggdata, Group.1==6 & Group.2==0.05)$x
[1] 0.9315789
```

Comment: Why would you prefer subset? Just cause it's a bit neater?

Comment: @naught101 yes, just because it's simpler and doesn't repeat any elements unnecessarily.

Answer (score 9):

There is a really helpful document on subsetting R data frames at:
http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/modules/subsetting.htm

Here is the relevant excerpt:

> Subsetting rows using multiple
>   conditional statements: There is no
>   limit to how many logical statements
>   may be combined to achieve the
>   subsetting that is desired. The data
>   frame x.sub1 contains only the
>   observations for which the values of
>   the variable y is greater than 2 and
>   for which the variable V1 is greater
>   than 0.6.
>
> `x.sub1 <- subset(x.df, y > 2 & V1 > 0.6)`

Comment: This link seems to be actual: http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/faq/subset_R.htm. Not know for sure but the quoted fragment is there.