# R: How can I delete rows if an element in a row satisfies certain characteristic?

Tags: r, delete-row

I am trying to figure out a way to delete rows of matrix if a cell in that row satisfies a certain characteristic. For example:

```
> mm <- matrix(c(1,2,3,2,3,4,1,2,3,4),5,2)
> mm
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    4
[2,]    2    1
[3,]    3    2
[4,]    2    3
[5,]    3    4
```

I want to delete rows if the 1st column element in that row is 2. At the end I want this:

```
   [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    4
[2,]    3    2
[3,]    3    4
```

How could I do this?

And what about a more general method if instead of deleting all rows who's first column element is 2, I needed to delete rows who's first column element corresponds to a set of numbers that are contained in a list? For example

```
delete_list <- c(2,3)
```

What is the best way to do this?

Thank You in advance.

Comment: Contained within [How to select rows from data.frame with 2 conditions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1536590/how-to-select-rows-from-data-frame-with-2-conditions) (and within every introduction to R manual ever written).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just use

```
mm2 <- mm[mm[,1]!=2,]
```

This works because

```
mm[,1] != 2
```

returns

```
[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

and essentially you are using this boolean array to choose which rows to pick.

Answer (score 2):

Not tested...

```
newmat <- mm[mm[,1]!=2,]
```

is basically what I think you're after.

Edit: damn, ninja'd by one minute!