# Delete multiple rows based on some constrains

Tags: r, dataframe, filtering, delete-row

I'm using R and I am trying to delete some rows from a data frame based on some constrains. so, if I got

```
dat <- data.frame(Cs=c("c1","c2","c3","c4","c5","c6"),  
  R1=sample(c("Y","N"),6,replace=TRUE), R2=sample(c("Y","N"),6,replace=TRUE),
  R3=sample(c("Y","N"),6,replace=TRUE), R4=sample(c("Y","N"),6,replace=TRUE),
  R5=sample(c("Y","N"),6,replace=TRUE), R6=sample(c("Y","N"),6,replace=TRUE))
```

I'd like to delete all the rows having a "N" at some given columns such as R1, R3, R4. For one single column, I found this solution: [delete row for certain constrains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8420288/r-how-can-i-delete-rows-if-an-element-in-a-row-satisfies-certain-characteristic)

```
d <- dat[dat[,"R1"]!="N",]
```

which works fine. but if I put multiple columns as

```
d <- dat[dat[,c("R1","R3","R4")]!="N",]
```

I got lots of extra rows full of NA. So where am I wrong?

Comment: So if there is any 'N' in any of your columns of interest, you want to remove the row?

Comment: exactly! I forgot to say it. sorry

Comment: Try `dat[rowSums(dat == "N") == 0, ]`

Comment: it seems not to work. I got an empty data frame

Comment: @Stefano, that is likely because there was no row without an N in the sample you tested

Comment: @docendodiscimus but the purpose is to delete only the rows with N at some given columns

Comment: @Stefano, see my update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
dat[rowSums(dat[, c("R1","R3","R4")] == "N") == 0, , drop=FALSE]
#  Cs R1 R2 R3 R4 R5 R6
#5 c5  Y  Y  Y  Y  Y  Y
```

Or, if you don't like excessive typing:

```
dat[!rowSums(dat[c('R1','R3','R4')]=='N'),]
```

This will first test each "cell" of columns "R1", "R3" and "R4" of your data whether it is equal to "N" and then calculate the sums of TRUE values per row. If no "N" is present in a row, the sum is equal to 0 and will be kept. I added `drop=FALSE` to keep the structure as a `data.frame`.

Note after a comment by OP:

If you subset only 1 column of a `data.frame` without specifying a `drop=TRUE` option, the default behavior of `[.data.frame` is to coerce the resulting 1-column-data.frame to an atomic vector. Then, `rowSums` wouldn't work on that resulting vector. To avoid that, change your code to:

```
dat[!rowSums(dat[,'R1', drop=FALSE]=='N'), ]
```

Sample data:

```
set.seed(5) 
dat <- data.frame(Cs=c("c1","c2","c3","c4","c5","c6"),  
                  R1=sample(c("Y","N"),6,replace=TRUE), R2=sample(c("Y","N"),6,replace=TRUE),
                  R3=sample(c("Y","N"),6,replace=TRUE), R4=sample(c("Y","N"),6,replace=TRUE),
                  R5=sample(c("Y","N"),6,replace=TRUE), R6=sample(c("Y","N"),6,replace=TRUE))
```

Comment: How would you incorporate testing only specific columns? Could you do `dat[rowSums(dat[,c("R1","R3","R4")]== "N") == 0, , drop=FALSE]`?

Comment: Thanks a lot! short and clean solution and it works. just one remark. you say "if the sum is equal to 0, the row will be kept" but I guess it's the opposite, isn't it?

Comment: @Stefano, no, it is as I said. If the number of "N"s in a row (and the specified columns) is 0, the row is kept. You can look at the row sums of my example: `rowSums(dat[c('R1','R3', 'R4')]=='N') #[1] 1 3 2 1 0 2`. You see that in the fifth row, there are no "N"s and that is the row that is kept in the example

Comment: @docendodiscimus yes sorry. my bad! I got "if N is present" and not "if no N"... thanks again!

Comment: You could also add the `dat[!Reduce('+',lapply(dat[c('R1','R3', 'R4')],'==', 'N')),]`

Comment: Yes! actually it might work even better as by using the other it crashes with a single column, while this not. thanks!

Comment: @Stefano, just change the code to `dat[!rowSums(dat[,'R1', drop=FALSE]=='N'),]`. `drop=FALSE` is required if you subset only 1 column of a `data.frame` and you want to keep it as a `data.frame` (instead of converting it to an atomic vector).

Answer (score 0):

You could make a 'keep'-variable consisting of booleans for each row:

```
keep <- apply(dat[,c("R1","R3","R4")],
                  MARGIN=1,
                  FUN=function(x){all(x!='N')})
res <- dat[keep,]

> res
  Cs R1 R2 R3 R4 R5 R6
1 c1  Y  Y  Y  Y  Y  Y
```

data:
seed used: 1234

```
dat <- structure(list(Cs = structure(1:6, .Label = c("c1", "c2", "c3", 
"c4", "c5", "c6"), class = "factor"), R1 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("N", "Y"), class = "factor"), R2 = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("N", "Y"), class = "factor"), 
    R3 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("N", 
    "Y"), class = "factor"), R4 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L), .Label = "Y", class = "factor"), R5 = structure(c(2L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("N", "Y"), class = "factor"), 
    R6 = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("N", 
    "Y"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Cs", "R1", "R2", "R3", 
"R4", "R5", "R6"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```