# select single value based on multiple attributes/col values in data frame in r

Tags: r

This should be a common question, but I was only able find an old question with a complicated answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1536590/how-to-select-rows-from-data-frame-with-2-conditions). Say I have a table for flight delays and I want to select specific `delay` time based on attributes like `direction` and `week`?

```
df<- data.frame(
  Quarter = paste0("Q", rep(1:4, each = 4)),
  Week = rep(c(1:8), each = 2, times = 1),
  Direction = rep(c("Inbound", "Outbound"), times = 8),
  Delay = c(10.8, 9.7, 15.5, 10.3, 11.8, 8.9, 5.5,
            3.3, 10.6, 8.8, 6.6, 5.2, 9.1, 7.3, 5.3, 4.4)
)
```

A proposed answer of the above post look like this:`df[df[,"Week"]=="1" & df[,"Direction"]=="Outbound","Delay"]`. Is there a better way to do this without repeating data frame name, something simpler in tidyverse? I want to select a *single* element at a time, something like subsetting with `[[`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `filter` and `select` :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  filter(Quarter == 'Q1', Direction == 'Inbound') %>%
  select(Delay)

#  Delay
#1  10.8
#2  15.5
```

If you need a vector as output use `pull` instead of `select`.

---

In base R, you can do this as :

```
subset(df, Quarter == 'Q1' & Direction == 'Inbound', select = Delay)
```

Comment: Hi thx for the answer. I modified my q a bit. My example wasn't accurate. I want to select a single element, instead of a subset or a data frame. I see that `subset` and or piping with `select` return a list instead.

Comment: How is the modified version any different? You can do `df %>% filter(Week == 1, Direction == 'Outbound') %>% pull(Delay)` or with `subset`, `subset(df, Week == 1 & Direction == 'Outbound')$Delay` . Is that what you want?

Comment: list contains name of the variable. But I want to get the number only. So basically after I use `subset`, I still need to use `[[` to extract the number.
```> result[[1]]
[1] 10.8
```

Comment: If you use the code from my comment above `result <- subset(df, Week == 1 & Direction == 'Outbound')$Delay` you don't need `[[`.